# Is there any ways to code vertical tabs in Tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I want to make tabs in settings page. The only problems is I don't want small horizontal tabs, but large vertical tabs. Bit I don't know how to code these vertical tabs. Could anyone help me solve this?

Vertical tabs:

[image: Vertical tabs]

Horizontal tabs:

[image: Horizontal tabs]